# ext4.vhdx corrupted after mounting with guestmount

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) dual boot,yesterday i tried to mount the WSL2 disk image `ext4.vhdx` from ubuntu using guestmount, this is the command i used:

```bash
sudo guestmount --add /path/to/ext4.vhdx -i --rw /mnt/myubuntu
```

at first it worked with no problem, but today when i wanted to do it again and access the WSL2 files i got this error:

```
guestmount: access: /mnt/asus/Users/root1/Documents/WSL/Ubuntu/ext4.vhdx: Input/output error
```

even when i just try to run `ls` against the file:

```
ls: cannot access 'ext4.vhdx': Input/output error
```

[when i try to ls ext4.vhdx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BHIy.png)

also when i boot from windows i get a notification saying that i have some files corrupted on my`C:` drive and when i run WSL it says that the ext4.vhdx is `corrupted and unreadable`, I run the check on `C:` drive then reboot, but no luck, also running `chkdsk /f C:` gives an error saying the volume is in use by another proccess.

is there a way to recover the disk image or at least some file inside it?

Thanks in advance